# Какую операцию выполняет get без скобок () в выражении. Angular @Directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

Есть следующий пример в документации Angular :
[API > @angular/core](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding)
Какую операцию выполняет get в этом выражении и где в документациях можно с ним ознакомиться?

```
@HostBinding('class.valid') get valid() { return this.control.valid; }
```

Полностью:

```js
@Directive({selector: '[ngModel]'})
class NgModelStatus {
  constructor(public control: NgModel) {}
  @HostBinding('class.valid') get valid() { return this.control.valid; }
  @HostBinding('class.invalid') get invalid() { return this.control.invalid; }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="prop">`,
})
class App {
  prop;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандарте JavaScript ECMAScript 5 была предложена концепция методов доступа: для доступа к свойству определяется пара методов - **get**-метод для получения значения свойства и **set**-метод для установки значения.

Использование аксессоров или методов доступа позволяет управлять тем, как значение устанавливается и как оно возвращается.

Методы доступа определяются как обычные методы, только перед ними ставятся ключевые слова **get/set**. **Set**-метод контроллирует установку значения, а **get**-метод возвращает значение.

Ссылки на источники:

- [Методы доступа](https://xsltdev.ru/typescript/guide/oop/get-set/#_1)
- [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)
- [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) - это синтаксическая конструкция языка, позволяющая определить в классе либо объекте свойство-геттер.

Обращение к такому свойству выглядит как обращение к полю, а не к методу.

```js
const obj = {
  log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  get latest() {
    if (this.log.length == 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
}

console.log(obj.latest);
// expected output: "c"
```